# How to format a text using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text that has format characters in curly braces.

```
let str = "My name is {name} and age is {age}!";
```

I want to change this with an object properties.

```
var myobj = { name: "x", age: "25" }
```

The result text should be `"My name is x and age is 25!"`

I can get the name and age values in text using regex.

```
let regex = /\{([^}]+)\}/g;
let matches = str.match(regex).map(x => x.replace(/[{}]/g, ""));
```

`matches` is array `["name", "age"]`

But how can I replace with object properties using regex? Is possible a short way?

Comment: Just to verify, does it *have* to be regex? A template literal can do it easier: `\`My name is {myobj.name} and age is {myobj.age}!\`` or even `\`My name is {name} and age is {age}!\`` if you make sure `name` and `age` are variables.

Comment: `str.replace(regex, (x,y) => myobj[y] ? myobj[y] : x)`

Comment: @VLAZ, I need regex solution, I know your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `.replace` method and get the value from `myobj` by key that you already capture into Group 1 with your current regex:

```js
let str = "My name is {name} and age is {age} {x}! {missing from myobj}";
var myobj = { name: "x", age: "25", x: ""}
let regex = /{([^{}]+)}/g;
console.log( str.replace(regex, (x,y) => myobj[y] !== undefined ? myobj[y] : x) );
// or a bit more modern variation
console.log( str.replace(regex, (x,y) => myobj[y] ?? x) );
```

If the key captured is present (`myobj[y] ??`), the corresponding value will be returned. If there is no key found with the regex in `myobj`, the whole match will be returned (`x`). If you need to return a value without braces if the key is not found, use `y` instead of `x` here.

There is no need to escape `{` or `}` in the pattern since they cannot be parsed as a limiting quantifier (in these cases, JavaScript RegExp engine does some "smart" parsing).

Comment: `myobj[y] || x` makes more cleaner

Comment: @User863 it can also trigger by accident if the replacement is an empty string.

Comment: @VLAZ The replacement is a callable here, it is not an empty string. `[^{}]+` matches one or more chars, there will always be some text in between curly braces, so there will be no chance of searching for an empty string key.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I meant if `myobj[y]` is an empty string, that is falsey, so it will return the placeholder, instead of removing it. `str = "hello {foo}"; myobj = { foo: "" }` for example.

Answer (score 2):

## Regular expression

You can use [`String#replace` and specify a function as replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). This will allow you to replace the matched content if it matches a key or skip it;

```js
function replace(text, obj) {
  let regex = /\{([^}]+)\}/g;
  
  return text.replace(regex, (fullMatch, capture) => {
    //in case no replacement is found, use the initial as default
    let result = fullMatch; 
    
    //see if we have any replacement for this placeholder
    if (capture in obj) {
      result = obj[capture];
    }
    
    //return the value to be used instead of the placeholder
    return result;
  })
}

let str = "My name is {name} and age is {age}!";
let myobj = { name: "x", age: "25" };

console.log(replace(str, myobj));

console.log(replace("Hello, {location} is {age} years old", myobj));
```

Or much shorter if using the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). It may not be supported on older environments, so the code might need transpilation for older ones.

```js
function replace(text, obj) {
  return text.replace(
    /\{([^}]+)\}/g, 
    (fullMatch, capture) => obj[capture] ?? fullMatch
  );
}

let str = "My name is {name} and age is {age}!";
let myobj = { name: "x", age: "25" };

console.log(replace(str, myobj));

console.log(replace("Hello, {location} is {age} years old", myobj));
```

## Template literal

You can also just skip the regular expression if it's always the same string but the replacements can differ. Using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
function replace({name, age}) {
  return `My name is ${name} and age is ${age}!`;
}

let myobj = { name: "x", age: "25" };

console.log(replace(myobj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it String.prototype.replace with [a function as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter:%7E:text=Specifying%20a%20function%20as%20a%20parameter,-You).

```js
let str = "My name is {name} and age is {age}!";
var myobj = { name: "x", age: "25" };
let regex = /\{([^}]+)\}/g;
const res = str.replace(regex, (match, key) => myobj[key] || match);
console.log(res);
```